# Why isn't my program outputting anything in the console (using object-oriented programming in Python)?

Tags: python, oop, output

Here is my code. There are two files one contain the Book class object and one the tests the object. This is all in python

book.py

```
class Book(object):
     """Represents a book in a library."""

    def __init__(self, title, author, patron):

        self._title = title
        self._author = author
        self._patron = patron

    def title(self):
        """Returns Book Title"""
        return self._title

    def author(self):
       """Returns the Author's Name."""
       return self._author

    def patron(self):
       """Returns the name of the patron."""
       return self._patron

    def __str__(self):
        return "Title: " + self._title + "\n"
        return "Author: " + self._author + "\n"
        return "Patron Currently Assigned: " + self._patron
```

testScript.py

```
from patron import Patron
from book import Book

s = Book("Death", "William", "George")

s.title()
s.author()
s.patron() 
s.title()

str(s)
```

When I run the program testScript.py it isn't returning any errors yet nothing is showing on the console either. Do you know why nothing is showing up when I am calling the methods? I have tried using IDLE and eclipse and nothing is outputting on both.

Comment: you never `print` anything.

Comment: ... I didn't ask for code. I asked why it wasn't outputting anything in the console. I already had the code up and written... I never asked for code. As for off topic post down there and reason I quote. "Questions ASKING for code." I never asked for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is, I'm sure, the central confusion you're running into.

In an interactive interpreter, when you type this:

```
s.title()
```

The interpreter captures the return value and redirects it to stdout.  This is distinct from when you *run* the script; this will not happen.  Thus those lines say something along the lines of "execute the `title` method and then immediately discard the results."

You need to `print` what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
str(s)
```

to this:

```
print s
```

Remember you are defining the `__str__` method, so when you make:

```
print OBJECT
```

it will call the `__str__` method that returns a `string`.

You may **also** want to change your `__str__` method, so it returns a whole string:

```
return "Title: " + self._title + "\n" +\
    "Author: " + self._author + "\n" +\
    "Patron Currently Assigned: " + self._patron
```

**Edit**

Remember that is unuseful to return multiple times in sequence, because when the program reaches the first `return` it will exit the method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

```
    print s
    print s.title() 
    print s.author()  
    print s.patron
```

The problem with your code is that it is returning the attributes of book and not printing them.
You can also do like this :-
 instead of return statment inside the functions, put print statemenets

```
    def title(self):
        print self.title
```

and similarly for other functions.